# How can I define an new index command that works better for paragraphs?

Tags: indexing, paragraphs, imakeidx, makeindex

Suppose that, in the middle of my document, I have paragraph about owls:  `Here is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.`

I want to index this paragraph using imakeidx, so I write,
`\index{owls}Here is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.`

Problematically, however, if this paragraph ends up at the top of a new page k, then the entry for owls in the index refers to the previous page; it has a page "k-1" beside it rather than a "k" (see for example the minimal working example below).

The easiest solution is to move the `\index` command just inside the paragraph:  `Here\index{owls} is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.`

For me, however, this is not ideal.  I have a long document and many of the paragraphs have many associated `\index` commands.  Moving these `\index` commands inside their corresponding paragraphs makes the paragraphs less readable for editing.

While the above describes the simplest case of `\index`, there is a similar issue when specifying a page range.  I would like to simply write,
`\index{owls|(}Here is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.\index{owls|)}` rather than,
`Here\index{owls|(} is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.\index{owls|)}`.

This leads me to my question.  How do I define a new command `\indexn` that yields correct page numbers in the index for the following two cases:
`\indexn{owls}Here is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.` and, 
`\indexn{owls|(}Here is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.\indexn{owls|)}`?

A minimal working example of the issue is below.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

% This code block just generates 552 copies of the word "lorem".
\newcount\zz
\loop
lorem
\advance\zz1
\ifnum\zz<552
\repeat

\index{owls}Here is a paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.
%\index{owls|(}Here is a new paragraph about owls.  Owls are extraordinary.\index{owls|)}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mbox{}\index{owls}` or `\leavevmode\index{owls}` would work

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: +1 for a quite detailed question

Comment: An index is about words, not paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\mbox{}\index{owls}` or `\leavevmode\index{owls}` would work